# Best way to add button navigation (linkable buttons) in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, button

I already tried the obvious of adding ASP.Net buttons, but it completely throws off any pages with forms.

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonAddEvents" runat="server" Text="Add Events" class="navbutton" onclick="ButtonAddEvents_Click"  />
```

C#:

```
protected void ButtonAddEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("addevent.aspx");
}
```

I have tried a JavaScript button but same result occurs where it doesn't agree with pages with forms:

```
<button class="navbutton" onclick="window.location='addevent.aspx';">Add Event</button>
```

What is the best way to add a button with a link on a page in Visual Studio?

Comment: Why will you need a linkable button if all it does is a redirect? I'd say use anchor tag. If you need to modify the anchor text/link based on server response, then you can use asp:HyperLink. And your Javascript solution is supposed to work anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that shouldn't be happening,

a response redirect or changing the document or window location would redirect you anywhere you want' are you sure you want a response redirect, or you want a post?

if your redirecting is failing that means your other ASPX page is not working

the best option for a link is to use the href 
the other options is writing a button with a redirect just like you did

are you sure your application is redirecting to the correct page

try to use a "/" and always start from the root directory

for example is your page is on www.mypage.com/browse/start.aspx

your redirect link should look like :"/browse/start.aspx"

Comment: Hm okay, that is strange. Thank you for your information.